# Affected row in asp.net quiz application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

everything works fine but when press finish to end the quiz in order to view the results show this message

[image]

Code:

```
public partial class results : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        if (al == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }

        resultGrid.DataSource = al;
        resultGrid.DataBind();

        // Save the results into the database.
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // Calculate score
            double questions = al.Count;
            double correct = 0.0;


            for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer a = (Answer)al[i];
                if (a.Result == Answer.ResultValue.Correct)
                    correct++;
            }

            double score = (correct / questions) * 100;

            SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [UserName]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @UserName)";

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("QuizID", Session["QuizID"].ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserName", User.Identity.Name);

            int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                // Let's just notify that the insertion didn't
                // work, but let' s continue on ...
                errorLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your quiz results into our database.  Therefore, the results from this quiz will not be displayed on the list on the main menu.";


            }

        }


    }

    protected void resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "QuestionOrder=" + resultGrid.SelectedValue;
    }

    void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Profile.IsAnonymous == false)
        {
            if (Profile.Theme != "")
            {
                Page.Theme = Profile.Theme;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public partial class results : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        if (al == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }

        resultGrid.DataSource = al;
        resultGrid.DataBind();

        // Save the results into the database.
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // Calculate score
            double questions = al.Count;
            double correct = 0.0;


            for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer a = (Answer)al[i];
                if (a.Result == Answer.ResultValue.Correct)
                    correct++;
            }

            double score = (correct / questions) * 100;

            SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [UserName]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @UserName)";

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("QuizID", Session["QuizID"].ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserName", User.Identity.Name);

            int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                // Let's just notify that the insertion didn't
                // work, but let' s continue on ...
                errorLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your quiz results into our database.  Therefore, the results from this quiz will not be displayed on the list on the main menu.";


            }

        }


    }

    protected void resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "QuestionOrder=" + resultGrid.SelectedValue;
    }

    void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Profile.IsAnonymous == false)
        {
            if (Profile.Theme != "")
            {
                Page.Theme = Profile.Theme;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Feed with code use, please

Comment: The error is pretty clear, somewhere in your code you're attempting to convert a string to a date/time.  Likely in a SQL statement.  Where are you doing that?

Comment: this is code of result page

Comment: @David Any Solutions or Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you define your query, and it looks like the `DateTimeComplete` parameter is *probably* supposed to be a `DateTime` value:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [UserName]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @UserName)";
```

But here to define it as a `string` value:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

As the error states, it shouldn't be a `string`, but should be a `DateTime`.  Unfortunately, it looks like you're using the [`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) and [`ParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.aspx) WebForms objects, which are very outdated and, well, just awful.  And in particular it looks like it *requires* a `string` be provided for the value, making the whole thing kind of fragile (as you're experiencing).

Though I recommend moving away from the `SqlDataSource` objects overall, at the moment you *should* be able to get around this by specifying the `string` conversion when adding the parameter to something that SQL will understand:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(
    "DateTimeComplete",
    DbType.DateTime,
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
);
```